# orderedSetWithOrderedSet:range:copyItems: NSArray Equivalent

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, set

So we're converting some old code and I need to change

```
NSSet *set = [NSOrderedSet orderedSetWithOrderedSet:filteredSubcategories
                                                             range:[range rangeValue]
                                                         copyItems:NO];
```

into an array.  Is there some kind of array equivalent to this? Can someone help me do this?

https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsorderedset/1543292-orderedsetwithorderedset

Answer (score 0):

Please see below a solution, but  please check the initial purpose of using Set instead of Array in the original code. The change that you are going to make may reduce performance if originally using set is:
To prevent duplicate or if there is a check if an object exist inside a loop.. Array and Set have the same method name contains: but a huge difference on performance.

```
for (NSNumber *number in myArray) {

    if([myArrayOfCategories containsObject:@9]){ //O(n) worst look up
       ///do sthg
    }
}

for (NSNumber *number in myArray) {

    if([mySetOfCategories containsObject:@9]){ //O(1) fast lookup
        ///do sthg
    }
}


//Solution


NSIndexSet *indexSet = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(1, 3)];
NSArray* content = [filteredSubcategories objectsAtIndexes:indexSet];
```

Answer (score 0):

Either create `set` as in the OP and get its array representation, like this:

```
NSSet *set = [NSOrderedSet orderedSetWithOrderedSet:filteredSubcategories //... as in the OP
NSArray *array = [set array];
```

Or, if you don't need the `set`, just subrange `filteredSubcategories` array representation, like this:

```
NSArray *array = [[filteredSubcategories array] subarrayWithRange:[range rangeValue]];
```